# How can I hide soft buttons?

Tags: screen, buttons

I have a tablet with 3 soft buttons (Back, Home, Recent) with Android 7.1.

*Is there some way to hide them* (and consequently use the full available screen), or at least *dim* them?

(They are disturbing when watching a video with my favorite old video player, which is not able to hide them.)

Comment: See https://lifehacker.com/use-tasker-to-enable-immersive-mode-on-android-whenever-1792620764

Comment: @Firelord, thanks, I will try that relatively complicated procedure (requiring to install 2 or 3 new payed applications), but it seems that those application may be very useful for future problems / tweaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation Gestures for Android, featured app on XDA Developers will work for you. Its free for most of the features. It hides the navigation bar completely and enables gestures to operate the phone.

Refer to this page for details: [Navigation Gestures on XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/official-xda-navigation-gestures-iphone-t3792361)